# How to run `ionic serve` from Gulp script

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, e2e-testing

I am trying to setup end to end tests using protractor and gulp. So in order to execute my tests on the CI server I will need spin off a server which serves ionic my html/js/css.

I am not entirely sure how ionic cli triggers the server, does it have some sort of task runner under the hood? If so, could I trigger it from the gulp script?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant way but I believe this gets the job done.

First include `child-process` in your `gulpfile.js`

`var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

Create a new gulp task `startServer` like

```
gulp.task('startServer', function(){
    exec('ionic serve', function (err, stdout, stderr) {});
});
```

Pass this new task to your default task like,

`gulp.task('default', [/*'task1','task2',...,*/'startServer']);`

Then simply run `gulp` instead of `ionic serve` and you're all set.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: http://www.reddit.com/r/ionic/comments/362log/how_does_ionic_serve_all_work/, it starts its own web server (like when using WAMPP or XAMPP for example).

So, I actually went to test this and it indeed is true; if you're familiar with XAMPP or WAMPP, you can start your ionic project inside the `www` folder of WAMPP and then you'll be able to access it via http://localhost/myapp/www link (without using ionic serve command), if you've started your ionic app with ionic start myapp.

I'm not that experienced with Gulp, but you may look if this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server would help you achieve your task.

Comment: As this is to be run on the CI (continuous integration) server, you have to make sure that you depend on node packages rather than tools like XAMPP as this would make your CI process brittle. I am currently using similar gulp package to `gulp-live-server`, but I wonder if there is a way to tap into ionic cli commands.

Comment: Well, I would guess that if you can install ionic cli on the CI server then you could most probably run that ionic serve command. However, since ionic serve supposedly only starts up a http server (and sets up watches for file changes) then you could achieve probably similar thing with just gulp-live-server (or any that you use). However, truth be told I wasn't playing with that so I don't have the experience to be of further help unfortunately.